# Do I need port forwarding?

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcp, portforwarding

I'm sending simple messages from an Android client to a PC server using TCP sockets. They are on the same WiFi network (connected to the same router). Do I need port forwarding for this?

Comment: No, port forwarding is not required because you are in the same network. It could be required if you have peer isolation or some other "security" feature and need to connect with PC using your public IP.

Comment: Not port forwarding.. no. But if the PC has a software Firewall turned on.. you'll need to open the port (or at least make sure its open).

Comment: @Simon: Do I need to open port programmatically or the Firewall will notify user to allow access to that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to port forward. You might need to open the port on your firewall, however, so make sure you do so. Port forwarding is for opening ports to external networks.